# i want to delete item from listview without restarting actitvity

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

i want to delete a listview item on long press on that item . after deleting item i need to restart activity to see changes  but i want to  see changes instantly

i already tried notifyDataSetChanged(); but it didn't work i am taking data from sqlite database and put it in hashmaps and sending it to custom adapter
on long press one row is deleted from database but no changes take place in listview.

```
@Override
public View getView( final  int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.detailsimage);
    CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.detailcardView);
    TextView textmo =view.findViewById(R.id.detailsmo);
    TextView texttu =view.findViewById(R.id.detailstu);
    TextView textwe =view.findViewById(R.id.detailswe);
    TextView textth =view.findViewById(R.id.detailsthu);
    TextView  textfr =view.findViewById(R.id.detailsfri);
    TextView textsa =view.findViewById(R.id.detailssat);
    TextView textsu =view.findViewById(R.id.detailssun);

    final databasehandler db = new databasehandler(context);
    cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            db.deleteTitle(position+1);
            Toast.makeText(context,Integer.toString(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
    });

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashmap= arrayList.get(position);
            String string= hashmap.get("repeat");
            string = Objects.requireNonNull(string).trim();


            Toast.makeText(context,string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    HashMap<String, String> hashmap= arrayList.get(position);
    String string= Objects.requireNonNull(hashmap.get("repeat")).trim();
   String[] separated = Objects.requireNonNull(string).split("");

                        }
            }}
 return view;
 }
}
```

Comment: You have to delete the item from list to see changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `notifyDataSetChanged` it will refresh the entire list, which will affect the performance

```
cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        db.deleteTitle(position+1);
        yourArrayList.remove(position);
        Toast.makeText(context,Integer.toString(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the list into the Adapter and change this block

```
cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        db.deleteTitle(position+1);
        yourList.remove(position);
     Toast.makeText(context,Integer.toString(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should reload data in your custom adapter. From what you described I understood It's not bound with the database in any way, so why do you expect it to reload even after calling `notifyDataSetChange()`? `notifyDataSetChange` works when you have actual observers registered in your Adapter.

Have a look at `Loaders`'s and `Content Providers` in order to automatically reflect database state in your `ListView`. Here's the link - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders

Answer (score 0):

Please create Custom Array list :-

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(); 
    al.add("item 1"); 
    al.add("item 2"); 
    al.add("item 3"); 
    al.add("item 4"); 
    al.add("item 5");
```

set adapter:-

```
StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Remove item from position

```
al.remove(position);
```

Now Refresh listview adapter:-

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```